# std::unique_ptr and inner type constraints

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

### I have

Templated class, like

```
template <typename T> 
class CHDF5Raster
{
   public:
       CHDF5Raster(); 
       ~CHDF5Raster()
       {
          if (m_Writing)
          {
            status = H5Fflush(m_H5File, H5F_SCOPE_GLOBAL);
            if (status < 0)
            ....
          }
       }
       ....
}
```

after in the code I define

```
std::unique_ptr<CHDF5Raster<int>[]>    raster;
```

and in some other place, due the dynamics of the code

```
m_pCatchRasterR8.reset(new  CHDF5Raster<int> [DYNAMIC_NUMBER]);
```

Nice and sweet. Everything compiles fine.

But at the moment I run

**EDIT**

Forget to mention that I use *Microsoft VC 2012* compiler and *Intel Composer 2013*. 
Both of them produce the same result.

### What I get

A linking error

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external  symbol __imp_H5Fflush
>   referenced in function  "public: __cdecl
>   CHDF5Raster::~CHDF5Raster(void)"
>   (??1?$CHDF5Raster@H@@QEAA@XZ)

A *linking* error on `H5Fflush`, which is a function of the linked library. There are also other linking errors on the library calls (this is not the only one), I just omitted them for simplicity.

### Questions:

1. Why I get ***linking*** error after defining `std::unique_ptr` over dynamic array, while without it everything is perfectly fine?
2. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you're not linking with the library. How are you linking, and how are you specifying that the library be linked?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: how can I not link to it if my code actually compiles, runs and produces correct results without application of `std::unique_ptr` ?

Comment: Possibly your code without `unique_ptr` never deletes the object, so the destructor (and hence the library function) isn't called. How are you linking, and how are you specifying that the library be linked?

Comment: show it nevertheless. The problem may be in the standard library, or the ``unique_ptr`` stuff.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I used dynamic linking via `xxx.lib` from the properties of the project.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: your words made born suspicions inside me, let me check for a moment.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: 1st. you are right, destructor wasn't called. 2nd I called it explicitly (like a function call on single element of the array) and also via `delete[]` on entire array. Program runs. No linking error present.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I found the cause, but not the reason. If I move the initialization of `std::unique_ptr` to function local scope (where it's used, so let's assume that function bounds are enough for its lifetime, hence for program correct run), no any linking error appears. It "looks" like during the linking, if `unique_ptr` is defined in global scope (class H file), somehow linker has not yet acess to that function definitions. Don't know if this will shine a light on some of your ideas.